# A proof-verification is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked the community to check [my proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169941/showing-existence-of-roots-of-a-complex-number) for correctness.

After reading a comment today I believe the proof is not correct. But I can't do anything because my question was closed as a duplicate.

It is not clear to me how my proof is a duplicate. The proof in the other thread is not the same. The person made different mistakes.

Is it possible to reopen my question? I really need help...

Comment: For what is worth, I see no mistakes in your proof. You might want to argue more carefully why $e^{2\pi i (k-j)/n}=1$ implies $k=j$, for example noting that $2\pi$ is the least positive real number for which $e^{it}=1$. You can even take this as the definition of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question has now been reopened. You did the right thing by coming to meta.

In general, you have the following options when you feel a question (not necessarily your own) shouldn't have been closed:

- Posting in the [dedicated chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/reopen-undelete-close-delete);
- Posting in the [dedicated thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19042/43351) as an answer;
- Editing your question to indicate it is not a duplicate. Editing automatically sends your question to the queue for reopening candidates.

In particular, for future reference, it is best not to create a separate thread for every question that ought to be reopened. The dedicated thread was installed with the purpose of limiting the number of questions like this one.